# when i use pydicom, errror printed..IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: list, indexing, pydicom

Using pydicom to try to read a test file like so:

```
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files

pass_dicom = "CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm"
filename = get_testdata_files(pass_dicom)[0]
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 4, in <module>
    filename = get_testdata_files(pass_dicom)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide the code as actual text and not an image of it.

Comment: I edited your question to include the code, as @Shai suggested. Note that it was not a great question in other ways - there was no indication of what you'd tried, and there reproductoin code included some extraneous elements. Please consider reading and applying https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask when asking your next question. It will help the answerers help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to read in a single DICOM file, use `pydicom.data.data_manager.get_files` method.  You need to provide two arguments: base and pattern.  Per the documentation, base is the base directory to recursively search as a string and pattern is a string pattern to filter the files (defaulted to "*").  Enter the full path to where your DICOM image is located (excluding the file name) for base and enter the DICOM image name for pattern.  The result will be a list with only one element so make sure to write `[0]` at the end.

So,

```
    import pydicom
    import pydicom.data
    base = "path/to/folder/containing/DICOM/file"
    pass_dicom = "CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm"
    filename= pydicom.data.data_manager.get_files(base,pass_dicom)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_testdata_files` looks for files in `lib\site-packages\pydicom\data\test_files` under your python installation.

"CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm" does not appear to be one of the supplied sample files (at least I don't have it with pydicom 1.1.0). So get_testdata_files is returning an empty list (`[]`) and when you try to get the 0th item, it raises an exception because there is no 0th item.

In the future, when debugging these kinds of errors, consider decomposing your code. Once you find a problem with `get_testdata_files(pass_dicom)[0]`, try `get_testdata_files(pass_dicom)`. See what its result is, and why.

And remember, the pydicom source is available online and installed on your own computer, so you can always see (for example) what `get_testdata_files` is trying to do.